# Yii2: где в документации можно прочитать про передаваемую конфигурацию в ActiveForm::begin()

Tags: yii2

Не могу пока освоиться с документацией (ну и/или с логикой работы Yii2).

Допустим, я хочу добавить форме `ActiveFrom` CSS-класс. Это делается так:

```
ActiveForm::begin([

  'method' => 'get',

  'options' => [

    'class' => 'my-css-class'

  ]

]);
```

Я не могу найти где это описано в документации, в частности, про `options`: что за они и почему именно туда нужно класть CSS-класс, а не по аналогии с другими атрибутами, которые передаются не в `options`.

Я перешёл на страницу [ActiveForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html), оттуда к методу [begin()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-widget.html#begin()-detail),   который наследуется от `yii\base\Widget`; там сказано, что метод принимает массив конфигурации:

```
public static static begin ( $config = [] )
```

- $config | array | Name-value pairs that will be used to initialize the object properties
- return - static - The newly created widget instance

Где именно я должен искать информацию по обработке пар имя-значения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае все просто, метод begin() создает экземпляр класса виджета при помощи [Yii::createObject()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-baseyii.html#createObject()-detail), который, в совою очередь, использует [контейнер внедрения зависимостей](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html).

В итоге значения элементов массива, переданного методу begin() присваиваются соответствующим свойствам нового объекта. На вашем коде это [**method**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$method-detail) и [**options**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$options-detail).

Назначение свойств виджета достаточно подробно описано в документации ($options - The HTML attributes (name-value pairs) for the form tag).

Другими словами, в массиве переданном begin(), вы устанавливаете значения свойств виджета.